# Obserable returning undefined when called initially

Tags: angular

I am writing property in angular 8 application that checks for availability of the service. The property calls the observable to check and returns true or false.
I am trying to call this property in my auth guard service. The problem that I am facing is that when the first time the property is called it returns undefined and later I see code within the subscribe being executed. By the time it executes the if block check on the property already has undefined hence doesn't get executed
How do I handle this?

What I am trying to achieve is to redirect users to the offline page from the auth guard itself by checking if TE service is available. Could somebody tell me what the problem is

The conditional block that I have added in the auth guard service is

```js
if (!isServiceAvailable) {
    this.router.navigate(['/offline'])
    return false
}
```

Auth guard service

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad {
    constructor(
        private authService: AuthService,
        private router: Router,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private connectionService: ConnectionService
    ) {}
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url
        return this.checkLogin(url)
    }
    canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.canActivate(route, state)
    }
    canLoad(route: Route): boolean {
        let url = `/${route.path}`
        return this.checkLogin(url)
    }
    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        let isLoggedIn = this.authService.isLoggedIn
        let isSessionExpired = this.authService.isSessionExpired
        let isServiceAvailable = this.connectionService.isApiAvailable
        if (!isServiceAvailable) {
            this.router.navigate(['/offline'])
            return false
        }
        // user is logged in and session didn't expire
        if (isLoggedIn && !isSessionExpired) {
            return true
        }
        if (isLoggedIn && isSessionExpired) {
            this.authService.refreshLogin().subscribe()
            return true
        }
        // redirect and logout
        this.authService.loginRedirectUrl = url
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        this.authService.logout(isLoggedIn && isSessionExpired)
        return false
    }
}
```

**Connection service**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ConnectionService {
    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private configurationService: ConfigurationService
    ) {
        const source = timer(0, Number(environment.corePingIntervalSeconds) * 1000)
        source.subscribe(() => {
            this.checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
                .pipe(first())
                .subscribe(
                    resp => {
                        //  if (resp.status === 200 ) {
                        //   // console.log(true)
                        //  } else {
                        //  //  console.log(false)
                        //  }
                    },
                    err => console.log(err)
                )
        })
    }
    get isApiAvailable(): boolean {
        let isAvailable: boolean
        this.checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                resp => {
                    if (resp.status === 200) {
                        isAvailable = true
                    } else {
                        isAvailable = false
                    }
                },
                err => console.log(err)
            )
        return isAvailable
    }
    checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable() {
        var pingUrl = this.configurationService.baseUrl + '/api/online'
        return this.httpClient.get(pingUrl, {
            observe: 'response'
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `if(isServiceAvailable)` be `if(!isServiceAvailable)`? Right now it would redirect to offline when the service IS available.

Comment: Yes you are right. I have amended my logic but that doesnt fix the real issue

Comment: When something returns an Observable or a promise, it's a pretty good sign that the result is **asynchronous**. I.e. the value can't be returned immediately, but it will be available later, and will notify you when it is by calling the callback passed to subscribe. Trying to return true or false immediately from a method that creates an observable and subscribes to it to get the result makes no sense. Just like wanting to butter a toast immediately after putting it in the toaster, without waiting for the toaster ding. Or trying to read the response to an email you've just sent.

Comment: You need to learn about asynchrony. Your service should return an Observable<boolean>. Not a boolean. And it shouldn't subscrbe to the http observable it creates, but should transform it into an Observable<boolean> using an operator.

Comment: I understood your first comment but not the second

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `isAvailable` before the observable has completed. You need to change it so that the function returns the observable:

```
get isApiAvailable(): Promise<boolean> {

    return this.checkIfCoreApiIsAvailable()
        .pipe(
          first(),
          map(resp  => {
            if (resp.status === 200 ) {
              return true;
            }

            return false;
          })
        )
        .toPromise();
    }
```

Then you need to handle the observable response here:

```
let isServiceAvailable = await this.connectionService.isApiAvailable;
```

Notice how I converted the observable to a promise so that you can use `await` without having to change too much of your code. Make sure to prepend the `checkLogin` function with the `async` keyword or using `await` will throw error.

If you don't want to use a promise you can simply tweak the code to listen for the observable response instead.

Comment: Please also change the signature of the function, right now you say it returns a boolean. You also miss the return keyword

Comment: I am getting error Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'OperatorFunction<{}, boolean>'.

Comment: Added the import import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

Comment: It still throws error Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean>'.
  Property 'then' is missing in type 'Observable<{}>'

Comment: @Tom At which line?

Comment: There is red squiggly on each line

Comment: @Tom There was a missing parenthesis, I updated answer. Try now.

Comment: I see you use await. How do i use it in mu case. it says the function needs to be modified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201203/discussion-between-chrillewoodz-and-tom).